# How to change my first name on a French passport?

Tags: passport, names

My name is Dayanna Pritchett.  My mother is French and my deceased father is American. I was born in France and now have been living in the US many years. I am still a French citizen. My situation is that my passport has a different first name than my green card and US driver's license. My first name on passport is Tania Pritchett.  Will there be problems traveling abroad?

Comment: On the French side, the name on the passport is based on what is declared on the birth certificate. Which first name is on yours ?

Comment: Similar to @audionuma I wonder why the green card and subsequent documents dont match the French passport.

Comment: It's also a bit unusual that you did not derive US citizenship from your father, but not impossible -- it implies that your father had not spent much time in the US before you were born, though the specific threshold depends on when you were born and whether your parents were married at the time of your birth.

Answer (score 3):

> Will there be problems traveling abroad?

It depends on what you want to do while you're traveling.  The most obvious problem is that you may want to go to a country that needs to see both your passport and your green card, for example to qualify for a visa exemption.  But I don't suppose many countries require visas of French citizens while exempting US permanent residents (for example, Canada has a visa exemption for green card holders, but also for French citizens, so you don't necessarily need your green card there).

You might run into trouble renting a car.  Some rental agencies want a passport or national ID card in addition to the driver's license.

But for the most part, you'll only need to show one of those documents at a time.  Entering the US, you'll need to show your green card and will probably be asked for your passport, but the US must already know about the discrepancy and I suspect is unlikely to care too much about it.

I just noticed that I overlooked the title question:

> How to change my first name on French passport

See https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F885

One thing to note:

> La demande de changement de prénom doit avoir un intérêt légitime.

For those who do not read French, this means that there must be a "legitimate interest" behind the request.  I think your desire to avoid complications from having different names along with the fact that you customarily use the other name should be sufficient, but that's just my opinion -- I have no experience with name changes under French law.

I also just noticed that you're not a US citizen.  You can see my earlier misstep in the edit history :-)

Comment: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F885?lang=en links to a decent english version.